# Why did this gas lift assist unit fail this way?

Tags: repair

I woke up to find one of the cover lift assists on my hot tub broken, bowed outwards.  This is the second time this has happened.  When installed, both ends are fixed so if it "decided" to extend while the lid is closed it would have nowhere to go but out, but I cant figure out why it would do this to prevent it in the future.  What causes a gas lifter to fail this way?

[image]

Comment: How many lift assists are there on the cover? When you changed them did you replace all of them or just the damaged one?

Comment: Because it's a cheap piece of crap like almost everything else these days? I'd try to retrofit a more robust part.

Comment: Did you happen to take any pictures of the failed strut while it was installed? There aren't many failure modes that would cause this, but there are a good number of ways to cause them

Comment: There are two, I replaced only the one that failed previously.  I now understand this may have been unwise.  This is the replacement that failed again.  I unfortunately did not take any photos of the strut while attached.

Answer (score 1):

The image is the result of an out-of-column force being applied to the mechanism. In the case of the gas lift device, either end of the attachment could have something in contact preventing the cylinder from following the expected angle change as the cover is raised or lowered.

Not to say that this is the specific cause, but if the tub end of the cylinder has a buckle hanging over the edge of the tub and it gets wedged into the area of the attach point for the cylinder, it could impede rotation of the cylinder and create the aforementioned out-of-column condition.

Comment: While this is one failure mode, it could also be caused by buckling if the gas strut seized from the inside

Comment: As the OP referenced a second time, it would certainly mean poor quality control if it's an inside job!

Comment: Without more information, it's even difficult to speculate, so who knows

Comment: Having had this same problem I agree with Fred. On my lift there was not a way to keep it solid while taking the cover off so I had to be careful that it was not skewed when putting on and taking off.